# Status of the three-body problem

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, open-problems, celestial-mechanics

I find many numerical results on the three-body problem, but what is rigorously proved? Especially I would be interested in the parameter domains for which we have rigorous lower bounds on the topological entropy or Lyapunov exponent of the system.

Comment: This question is too broad. There is enormous amount of knowledge about three body problem, in particular about Sun-Moon-Earth system. One cannot describe the "status" in a short answer.

Answer (score 9):

Although there is no solution for the general three body problem there are many related results, especially for the restricted case.   [Here is a study of LE's](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.5062) in restricted 3BP.  [And here is a classification scheme](https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.0950) for the mean motion resonance of the restricted 3BP including using the maximal LE for characterizing the resonances.  These will point you to many related results.  As a historical aside, Gutzwiller, in his book[1] says that the ancient Greeks knew there were 3 different lunar months (depending on how you measure them in they sky): the Sidereal month (27.32166 days), the anomalistic month (27.55455 days) and the nodical month (27.21222 days).  These result from 3 body interactions (earth, moon, sun).  The Greeks were apparently able to observe these to an accuracy of 1 second per month.  Gutzwiller calls these the first precision scientific measurements in history.  Every time I think about this I am astonished; it must have taken immense effort over centuries to compile the needed data.

[1] Martin C. Gutzwiller [Chaos in Classical and Quantum systems.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387971734)

Comment: Exactly, @AlexandreEremenko.    Don't think I mentioned instruments.  Just observations which I suppose we can call measurements.  Hundreds of years of observations.

Comment: I am aware of the numerical estimates of the Lyapunov exponent you refer to, but i am asking for a rigorous result.

Comment: Fair enough @JörgNeunhäuserer.  I'll keep poking around.  Good luck.

Comment: @JohnS By "no solution" do you mean no known bounds, in the general case, on the Lyapunov exponents or topological entropy? The reason I ask is that there is a kind of "folk belief" in certain circles that the differential equations describing the three-body problem have no solution, which is not true:
https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.acta/1485887350